# DataGrid Grouping - get each group rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping

I am using DataGrig Grouping for my data. In my group header I am using checkboxes for ColumnCheckBox cell check, for that I have to have rows data for each group.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount, StringFormat=({0})}"/>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

CS:

```
Instances = new ListCollectionView(types);
Instances.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("View"));
Instances.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Category"));
Instances.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Family"));
```

So an idea is to bind header checkboxes with array of Id for each row and on header check, change binded CheckColumn values. But for that i need to collect all group rows. Is it possible to implement?

So I've got: https://i.ibb.co/7g9GpqL/p1.png

And I need : https://i.ibb.co/WW7S4cn/p2.png